# Expecting 1-To-Many however creating 1-1 SQL

Tags: sql

I want to create a one to many relationship between two tables but for some reason a one to one relationship is being created.

It's strange because identical code for two other tables in the same DB are creating 1-Many relationships as expected.

Here is my code

```
CREATE TABLE thing
(
ThingID         INT         NOT NULL,
Words           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
OtherWords      INT         NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_TRIPID PRIMARY KEY (ThingID),

)


CREATE TABLE otherthing
(
ThingID         INT         NOT NULL,
Cost            SMALLMONEY  NOT NULL,
MoreWords       INT         NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT pk_Trip PRIMARY KEY (ThingID),
CONSTRAINT fk_Trip FOREIGN KEY (ThingID) REFERENCES thing(ThingID)  
)
```

Any help you can offer is very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Both tables have a primary key of `thingid`.

This prevents many being inserted in *either* table. The second table needs the primary key removed and ideally changed to a different primary key so that more than one row matching a given `thingid` can be inserted into it.

Comment: This still leaves me with a 1-1 relationship though, even with a different primary key

Comment: @j.m no it doesn't. What tool is telling you that?